# How to reproduce online CoreNLP.run openIE result locally

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to get triplets using CoreNLP from a sentence. However, my result from the java output is different with coreNLP.run online. For example

> The battery unit can be stored in a temperature between -20°C and +50°C, with a recommended storage temperature of +25°C

CoreNLP.run output is:

```
1. battery unit |can|can stored
2. battery unit |can|can stored in temperature
3. battery unit |can|can be stored in a temperature between -20°C and +50°C, with a recommended storage temperature
4. battery unit |can|can be stored in a temperature between -20°C and +50°C, with a recommended storage temperature of 25°C
```

java run output:

```
1.battery unit|can|can stored in temperature between -20 °C with recommended storage temperature of +25 °C
2.battery unit|can|can stored in temperature between -20 °C with storage temperature of +25 °C
 ...
 ...
```

My local run always missing last 3 and 4 triplets CoreNLPrun and none of my triplets have "between -20°C and +50°C," information.

I am running the program with this command
 `java -Xmx16g -cp "./*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,depparse,natlog,ner,openie`

My question is how can I get the triplets with "between -20°C and +50°C" information as output in `coreNLP.run`. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What version of Stanford CoreNLP are you running ?

Comment: I am using stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05

Comment: Update!!. If I use stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05 GUI version I can get the same result as corenlp.run. But can't get the same if I use commandline? Anybody observe this?